Replace recurring values of a flat array with an empty string
I am populating an array of dates from two sources: an array of dates and a range of dates between two dates.
$dateann = ['2024-08-16', '2024-08-11', '2024-08-16', '2024-09-16'];
$period = CarbonPeriod::between('2024-08-01', '2024-08-31');
foreach ($period as $date) {
    $days[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
$array_dates = array_merge($dateann, $days);

This can result in duplicate dates in the merged array.  I would like to replace any recurring dates with an empty string.
Current output:
array: [
  0 => "2024-08-16"
  1 => "2024-08-11"
  2 => "2024-08-16"
  3 => "2024-09-05"
  4 => "2024-08-01"
  5 => "2024-08-02"
  6 => "2024-08-03"
  7 => "2024-08-04"
  8 => "2024-08-05"
  9 => "2024-08-06"
  10 => "2024-08-07"
  11 => "2024-08-08"
  12 => "2024-08-09"
  13 => "2024-08-10"
  14 => "2024-08-11"
  15 => "2024-08-12"
  16 => "2024-08-13"
  17 => "2024-08-14"
  18 => "2024-08-15"
  19 => "2024-08-16"
  20 => "2024-08-17"
  21 => "2024-08-18"
  22 => "2024-08-19"
  23 => "2024-08-20"
  24 => "2024-08-21"
]

Desired output:
array: [
    0 => "2024-08-16"
    1 => "2024-08-11"
    2 => ""
    3 => "2024-09-05"
    4 => "2024-08-01"
    5 => "2024-08-02"
    6 => "2024-08-03"
    7 => "2024-08-04"
    8 => "2024-08-05"
    9 => "2024-08-06"
    10 => "2024-08-07"
    11 => "2024-08-08"
    12 => "2024-08-09"
    13 => "2024-08-10"
    14 => ""
    15 => "2024-08-12"
    16 => "2024-08-13"
    17 => "2024-08-14"
    18 => "2024-08-15"
    19 => ""
    20 => "2024-08-17"
    21 => "2024-08-18"
    22 => "2024-08-19"
    23 => "2024-08-20"
    24 => "2024-08-21"
]


Where are you stuck? Have you tried anything? Done any research? You can google this in a few seconds

I don't know how to recover the first duplicate value and remove duplicates except the first one

it's not what i want, i tried to use it but it's not the result i want to get

instead of the duplicate value I want to get a blank space (IT'S VERY DIFFERENT)

Loop through the array. Use array_search() to find the first index of the current value. If it's not equal to the current index, replace the value with an empty string.

if (array_search($value, $array) != $index) { $array[$index] == ''; }

Why would you want a blank space?? Surely that will just cause issues when you come to process this data later, as you'll have to have a special case to deal with empty spaces. What advantage do you get by keeping the empty ones?

@Barmar I put my code. Can you please let me know how to do it?

@ADyson In the table I have to print the rows with the data that refer to that date without repeating the date again in the next row

@maurice ok. You never said there was any other data involved.

Check if the current index is the same as the first index of the value. If not, replace the value with an empty string.
foreach ($array_dates as $index => $value) {
    if (array_search($value, $array_dates) != $index) {
        $array_dates[$index] = '';
    }
}


Perfect thanks. Is there a way to sort? I used sort but it doesn't work

I can't think of a reason why sort($array_dates) wouldn't work.

it only returns true and not the sorted array

It modifies the array in place, the return value is not needed.

Sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean? I tried to do dd(($array_dates)); and it returns true

Don't do $array_dates = sort($array_dates);. Just call sort() without the assignment.

I simply wrote it like this: dd(sort($array_dates));

Do sort($array_dates); dd($array_dates);. sort() doesn't return the sorted array.

As a performance comparison, making value-based searches using array_search() calls will be less efficient than making key-based searches.  Here is a demonstration of how to skip the merge step and use null coalescing techniques on a lookup array that only grows in size as unique dates are encountered.
Code: (PHPize Demo)
$dateann = ['2024-08-16', '2024-08-11', '2024-08-16', '2024-09-16'];
foreach ($dateann as &$date) {
    $date = $lookup[$date] ?? $date;  // if not in the lookup, it's new
    $lookup[$date] ??= '';  // flag the date in the lookup to only return an empty string
}
$period = CarbonPeriod::between('2024-08-01', '2024-08-31');
foreach ($period as $obj) {
    $ymd = $obj->format('Y-m-d');
    $dateann[] = $lookup[$ymd] ?? $ymd;  // if not in the lookup, it's new
    $lookup[$ymd] ??= '';  // flag the date in the lookup to only return an empty string
}
var_export($dateann);


Code works perfectly; i only give the best answer to the previous one just because it was given first. Thanks anyway

I would recommend using a filter function. Something like the following would work for this use case:
function filterDates(array $dates): array
{
    /** @var string[] The result array */
    $result = [];
    /** @var bool[] a lookup map for checking existence */
    $lookup = [];

    // loop through the array shifting each element off the front until empty
    while ($date = array_shift($dates)) {
        // check if already exists
        if (isset($lookup[$date])) {
            // set to empty string
            $result[] = '';
            continue;
        }
        // set lookup entry
        $lookup[$date] = true;
        // set date value
        $result[] = $date;
    }

    return $result;
}

The above function, simply works its way through the array while keeping track of dates already set, then setting the duplicates to an empty string.
You can then pass in the merged array and it will set each repeating entry to an empty string.
$array_dates = filterDates(array_merge($dateann, $days));


This is the premise of my answer except my script avoids the array_merge() step and the looped array_shift() calls.

Why are you bothering to consume the $dates array?  It would be simpler to use a foreach().
